# PHP Rest API Get

Tags: php, api, rest

I've tried a few different things, but everything I can find isnt working. I have a photo URL, and am trying to access it with the appropriate authentication

```
  $service_url = 'photo URL';
  $curl = curl_init($service_url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Bearer code'));
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "Username:Password"); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET'); // LINE 12

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); 
  $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
  $response = json_decode($curl_response);
  curl_close($curl);

  var_dump($response);
```

Obviously I'm trying to do a GET, but im not sure its working correctly. I'm also not sure that the

```
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Bearer code'));
```

line is working correctly.

Any ideas?

P.S. - The link is a https://

Thanks!

Comment: What is `$curl_response` after this is called?

Comment: Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /web/com/140330164410217/main.php on line 12 object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["error"]=> string(14) "not authorized" }

So it looks like there is an error on the 'GET' line, and its still not being authorized correctly

Comment: The warning is because you're using $curl_handle instead of $curl on that line, no?

Comment: You shouldn't need it though, GET is default.  I would remove it completely.  When curl expects something to be done differently, it sometimes flakes out, even if your request seems perfectly reasonable (like setting "GET").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a valid value for CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER

```
array('Bearer code')
```

You need a header name AND value, such as

```
array('Authorization: Bearer code')
```